# Configuring ESLint to work with AWS lambda layer

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, eslint

I am using ESLint to lint my AWS lambda code I have in a project. I am getting three linting errors that I cannot figure out how to use the config file to turn off.

On a module like this: `const {getUser} = require('opt/appsync/graphql/queries`);

I get these 3 linting errors:
[image: Linting errors]

However, this is the recommended approach on AWS docs to reference the lambda layer that the code will pull from. So I want a way to turn these errors off just for my lambda layers and not the whole code base. I have tried the eslint-import-resolver-alias but it does not appear to be working. What are my options?

Here is my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "globals": {
    "JSX": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }],
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"],
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }
    ],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "shared/node_modules"]
      },
      "alias": {
        "map": [["^opt$", "./opt/"]],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your eslint import resolver is setup incorrectly, the `^opt$` will only match "opt" and not everything that has opt in it. It should be

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "shared/node_modules"]
      },
      "alias": {
        "map": [["^/opt", "./opt/"]],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And of course, you will have to disable the `no-absolute-import` rule as well.